# html and svg sizing issue

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following HTML structure:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1234</div>
    <div class="cell">5678</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1234</div>
    <div class="cell"><div><svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg></div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    display: table-row;
    background-color: #DADADA;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lgal/6wywsva2/2/)

Can you tell me why the row with `svg` cell is higher then `25px`?

**NOTE**

The `svg` is rendered by a library, so I can't set its height.

Comment: You have different code over here and different code on your jsfiddle

Comment: The issue is the same in both version of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you clarified that the issue is with both codes of yours, so since svg is an `inline` element by default, you need to use `vertical-align: top;` inorder to get rid of the `height` disturbance..

```
svg {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wywsva2/3/)

It will be better if you assign an `id` to your svg element and modify your selector accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You've two issues.

1. SVG is an inline element as stated in the other answer, this can be solved by giving the svg a `vertical-align: top` style.
2. The `<svg>` is in an inner `<div>` element that has no width/height style. The `<div>` will size to its contents but the contents are an svg element that sizes to its container. The result should be that the cell sizes to the fallback 300 x 150 width/height which it does in Firefox.